# How to make my website avalible on local network

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost, lan

I'm currently working on my website which is running on nodejs usining expressjs, and everything is working fine. However I want to test my website from other devices, for example from my phone or other computer, which are connected to the same wi-fi. How am I supposed to do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to make sure that your websever computer is acccepting incomming request for this port, sometimes is necessary to set this up in the routing information on your router. disabling the firewall can also help with that if all of this is met by your computer other users should be able to get access to your server using your local Ip + port

Answer (score 0):

disabling firewall is a bad idea. You can open a specific port or if you dont want to go through that, just use something like https://ngrok.io

Answer (score -1):

Try to access your app with your locale ip address and your port. Something like that.

http://your.network.ip.address:port/ e.g. http://192.168.0.3:3000

Comment: Sorry, but it did not work. I have tried this and the error is ERR_CONNECTION_TIMEd_OUT

Comment: maybe your router is blocking the port you use with node. Or your computer don't allow external connexion. You will need to check your router/computer